# Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Theorem: Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations.

Proof: Would Cayley's Proof from 1854 suffice the proof to this theorem?

Comment: Whatever Cayley wrote in 1854, $G$ acts on itself by left translation.

Comment: Yes, G is any group. For each g within G we consider Tg: G->G and Tg: Tg(H)=gh
We use the left multiplication map and see Tg is a permutation of G. Now do i prove Tg is 1-1 and onto?

Comment: OK, thank you. I was making sure.

Comment: Yes, one has to show that $T_g$ is a permutation. Most simply by exhibiting a two-sided inverse.

Comment: Jsut a little point to avoid misunderstandings: it is **not** true that any group is isomorphic with some $\;S_n\;$ , of course, but with *some* subgroup of $\;S_n\;$ for some $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ . It looks pretty trivial yet...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).